# Track and save video progress for users

Tags: video, tracking, progress

I'm setting up a video platform and want to track where a user left off when they leave/close the page. The videos are hosted in an external platform called videoCypher which helps prevent the videos from being scraped but they don't offer anything to track videos at a user level since that logic is not relevant to them.

I currently send http requests every few seconds and when the user leaves the page to store the data in a table.

I'm curious if this is the way to go about this though, I've read about [navigator.sendBeacon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) which might lighten the load of theses requests but the clear drawback is having to pass the user in a parameter instead of an auth header.

Netflix/Prime/Youtube stream the video which leads me to assume the streaming server is in charge of keeping track of this.

Any thoughts?

BONUS Q: I'm also struggling with tracking if a video has been completely watched without the user simply skipping to the back of the video and watching the last few seconds.

Comment: Hi do you found any solutions for this problem? if yes can you pls share it?